# Generate a date range lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I need to transform the table below to give me a list of the periods with a close date, and the close date from the previous period. This will give me a date range for that period so that it look like the following:

```
NOV20 | 2020-12-10 | 2020-11-11
DEC20 | 2021-01-15 | 2020-12-10
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Heh... I think it ironic that this post was closed for a lack of "focus" and, yet, someone removed "MSSQL" from the title, which identifies a very focused need, added 4 spaces to each line in the desired results, and, for some reason, couldn't understand what the OP was after.  It's even more ironic that the person that removed the bit of focus from the title is one of the people that closed the question for a supposed lack of "focus" even though the point of the question was totally obvious by the examples given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *seem to* want to bring the preceding close date in each row. If so, use `lag()`:

```
select id, period, closedate, 
    lag(closedate) over(order by closedate) last_closedate
from mytable
```